# Auto set focus to button

Tags: angular

Cannot set focus on button upon input key enter event. Setting focus on inputs works well but same code on button doesn't working at all.

my.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]='myFG'>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex appearance="outline">
   <input matInput type="number" 
      #containerWeight>
       formControlName="containerWeight"
       (keydown.enter)="cwInput(containerWeight.value)">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex appearance="outline">
    <input matInput type="number" 
      #grossWeight
      formControlName="grossWeight"
      (keydown.enter)="gwInput(grossWeight.value)">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
      <button mat-raised-button   
         #doneBut 
         color="accent">
       DONE
     </button>
  </div>
```

my.component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('grossWeight') grossWeight: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('doneBut') doneBut: ElementRef;

 cwInput(containerWeight){ //this works perfectly
    if(containerWeight.length>0 && containerWeight>0){
      this.focusMe=!this.focusMe;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.grossWeight.nativeElement.focus(); //WORKING
      },0);
    }
  }

 gwInput(grossWeight){ 
    if(grossWeight.length>0 && grossWeight>0){
      this.focusMe=!this.focusMe;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.doneBut.nativeElement.focus(); //NOT WORKING
      },0);
    }
  }
```

This produce an error "Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why but your code works if you set the border to `button:focus` like this.

```
button:focus {
  border: 1pt solid transparent;
}
```

Check this working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ftsvw).